# Ошибок нет, но модуль не установился. Установка модуля nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: nginx

Делаю всё по науке, скачал свою версию nginx, сконфигурировал с добавлением модуля, далее собрал из исходников(make), и установил (make install), однако модуль не установился. Хотя ошибок никаких не было, вернее были но все устранил и последняя компиляция, установка была успешна. Подскажите, плз варинаты для исправления.

Имеющаяся информация:

nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

objs/nginx -V

```
 nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built by gcc 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/home/rezovskij/Загрузки/nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

Видно, что objs/nginx-V модуль подхватился.

Вывод make install

```
make -f objs/Makefile install
make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/rezovskij/nginx-1.14.0»
test -d '/usr/share/nginx' || mkdir -p '/usr/share/nginx'
test -d '/usr/share/nginx/sbin' \
    || mkdir -p '/usr/share/nginx/sbin'
test ! -f '/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx' \
    || mv '/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx' \
        '/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx.old'
cp objs/nginx '/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx'
test -d '/etc/nginx' \
    || mkdir -p '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/koi-win '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/koi-utf '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/win-utf '/etc/nginx'
test -f '/etc/nginx/mime.types' \
    || cp conf/mime.types '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/mime.types '/etc/nginx/mime.types.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params' \
    || cp conf/fastcgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/fastcgi_params \
    '/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf' \
    || cp conf/fastcgi.conf '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/fastcgi.conf '/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params' \
    || cp conf/uwsgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/uwsgi_params \
    '/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/scgi_params' \
    || cp conf/scgi_params '/etc/nginx'
cp conf/scgi_params \
    '/etc/nginx/scgi_params.default'
test -f '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' \
    || cp conf/nginx.conf '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
cp conf/nginx.conf '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default'
test -d '/run' \
    || mkdir -p '/run'
test -d '/var/log/nginx' \
    || mkdir -p '/var/log/nginx'
test -d '/usr/share/nginx/html' \
    || cp -R html '/usr/share/nginx'
test -d '/var/log/nginx' \
    || mkdir -p '/var/log/nginx'
test -d '/usr/lib/nginx/modules' \
    || mkdir -p '/usr/lib/nginx/modules'
test ! -f '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so' \
    || mv '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so' \
        '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so.old'
cp objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so'
test ! -f '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so' \
    || mv '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so' \
        '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so.old'
cp objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so'
test ! -f '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so' \
    || mv '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so' \
        '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so.old'
cp objs/ngx_http_geoip_module.so '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so'
test ! -f '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so' \
    || mv '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so' \
        '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so.old'
cp objs/ngx_mail_module.so '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so'
test ! -f '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so' \
    || mv '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so' \
        '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so.old'
cp objs/ngx_stream_module.so '/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so'
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/rezovskij/nginx-1.14.0»
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте его оттуда, куда установили (`/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx`), и всё должно быть в порядке.